# Jupyter notebook debugging is not working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging, jupyter-notebook

I want to debug Jupyter Notebook via VS Code but when I click on the debug cell, this window pops up.
Do you have any idea why is this happening? It happens for all ipynb files on my machine, not only for just one. After pressing on the debug cell, this option disappeares and have to reload the window to attempt to debug again.

Comment: What window? Where?